# Removing artist name from under song name in iTunes album view?

Tags: itunes, tags

I have a ton of music in my iTunes (Windows). When I go into Album View (or any view that has songs isolated by Album), in some random albums the song artist/composer is listed under the song. 99% of my songs don't do this and it bothers me that some of them do for no apparent reason. I've tried editing song information and I've compared songs with each other to see what is making certain songs do this, but found nothing. How can I disable this?

It should look like this:

```
1 American Idiot
2 Jesus of Suburbia
etc
```

not

```
1 American Idiot
  Green Day
2 Jesus of Suburbia
  Green Day
etc
```

Comment: Are you sure, these files don't have tags like composer or album artist? There has to be an information hidden somewhere in the tags. I suggest you, to use [mp3tag portable](http://portableapps.com/node/18890) and view+compare all tags of a good and a bad file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I double checked my tags and figured out that iTunes will only update way the songs are listed when it is restarted. The songs that were being listed like that were missing the Artist tag.